# R scatterplot overplotting color

Tags: r, scatter-plot

So far I have this:

```
qplot(df[[1]], as.numeric(rownames(df)), group=df[[2]], color=df[[2]], ylab="")
```

[image: Scatter plot]

I want to use different colors for the points in the 2 groups - perhaps a lighter shade for the what's in black now and a darker - say, red for what's in blue. Also, I want to use hexbin kind of thing for group=0 but not for group=1. I'm not able to get the syntax to get this working.  In the current plot 0 is in black and 1 is in blue.

> > Added:

I worked on it some more, and by using factor and scale_colour_manual, I got the grey color for 0 and red for 1:

```
> palette1
[1] "grey"   "red"    "blue"   "violet" "black" 
fy=factor(y, labels=c('grey', 'red'))
qplot(x, seq(1:length(x)),col=fy, ylab="") + geom_point() + scale_colour_manual(values=palette1)
```

[image: Scatter Plot]

Pending questions are:

How to first plot all the grey and then red on top (some of the red is now hidden because the grey is plotted over).

How to apply the hexbin logic for group0 i.e. the grey points only and not for the red.

Comment: Can you include your data?

Comment: You are probably going to need to split your data if you want part of it as points and the other part as `geom_hexbin`. I doubt that very many people have made such a plot, so most will need to test it out on real data, which you have been asked to provide. I would think you should post a link to a place where it could be downloaded rather than posting all of it here.

Comment: I'll need to figure out how to post the data to some place - this may take some time, I'm not currently set up for that.